# How to open a Fragment from an onClick Button within my activity

Tags: android, android-fragments

I'm currently working on a RPG for a school project and I am trying to get a button to link to and open one of my fragments. I have searched and examined solutions from many others who have asked, only to no avail. Here is my main activity code:
Main Activity Code:
[image]

Here is the code for the fragment:
Fragment Code:
[image]

I'm not really sure where I need to go next as I have already tried implementing "Fragment", "FragmentManager", "FragmentTransaction" and all that jazz. Thank you for your time and hope to hear from you all soon.

Comment: just define a framelayout on your mainactivity's xml layout and on click of the button, use getsupportfragmentmanager to add fragment.  You need to also provide an xml for your fragment. and create a class extending fragment

Comment: I have an XML for my fragment called "fragment_character_creation". Just clarifying, does that mean I need to say in the public void onClick method "getSupportFragmentManager = fragment_character_creation"? Sorry, I'm still learning the ropes here.